# How to i get the difference of time in hours for a file created time and the current time using perl

Tags: perl

How to i get the difference between a file created time and the current time in hours

Comment: possible duplicate of [using perl, difference of two timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460610/using-perl-difference-of-two-timestamp)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 4):

`stat($file)->mtime` gives you the last modification time in seconds. Subtract that from `time` and divide it by 3600 ... that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For calculations involving time or dates you can always rely on [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime)!

For your specific cuestion, you can use the constructor `from_epoch` to convert from Unix timestamp to DateTime.